# Can I two-way bind input field in directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having a following template in `templateUrl`:

```
<input name="foo" ng-model="test">
```

directive:

```
app
  .directive('bar', function() {
    return {
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(scope.test, function(newVal) {
          console.log(val);
        });
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'templates/foo.html'
    };
   });
```

can I two-way bind it in directive so I `scope.$watch` input variable?
I tried using `ng-bind` and `ng-model`, but I cannot access that variable in `scope` of my directive.

**Edit**
Added directive code.

Comment: Can you include an example of your directive?  `ng-model` should work.

Comment: change `scope.$watch(scope.test, ` to `scope.$watch('test', ` and it should work. But it will break again if you start using isolated scopes (just saying).

Comment: @Yoshi you can add it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
scope.$watch(scope.test, ...
```

to

```
scope.$watch('test', ...
```

and it should work. The first argument to [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) is the (so called) *watchExpression*. It will be evaluated against the relevant scope. When using a string you can basically use everything you would also use in the views/templates.

*Mind that this will break again if you start using [isolated scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).*